# How to consume WCF WebServices from PHP?

Tags: .net, php, wcf, soap

I have to consume a WCF WebServices but the WSDL contains bindings that PHP doesn't support also.

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: PHP-SOAP doesn't support transport 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/named-pipe'

How to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of the WCF services a solution is to remove manually the unsupported bindings from the WSDL and save the WSDL in another location and point to it using:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="test">
        <serviceMetadata 
           externalMetadataLocation="http://YourServer/Service/MyService.wsdl"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that you are exposing the service using the [net named pipe binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx).  This more than likely isn't going to work with php because it doesn't know how to speak SOAP/WS over named pipes.

Rather, you will want to use either the [basic HTTP binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding(VS.95).aspx) or the [WS HTTP binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx) to expose your service and *then* consume it in PHP.

Comment: It happens that I expose multiple bindings, including the ones you recommended for PHP. The problem is that my PHP client doesn't want the uncompatible ones to appear in the WSDL, and I don't know how to remove them from the WSDL.

Comment: @estourodepilha.com: You can turn off the MEX endpoints while getting the WSDL for the PHP client.  Note here that the PHP client should really ignore this, it's not necessarily a fault of WCF.